# Set scroll default position to bottom using CSS or Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

Currently the scroll default position is at the top

[Default Scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6Bdy.png) vs. [Bottom Scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDkG4.png)

By default when the user sees the page I would like to set the scroll position to bottom, how can I do that using SCSS or Angular?

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5dpver) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS solution

Use the last element on the page

```
var element = document.getElementById(id);
element.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: I'm using Angular, how can I do that the Angular way?

Comment: This is a pure javascript code. You can use this in Angular as well.